# How could Improve these simple dice rolling functions to produce histogram plots?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

## A faster way to code this?

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a quicker way to code this? I was tasked to make a dice rolling functions for 2-3 dice and display the results in a histogram. I know that while/for loops aren't the fastes in python. Could anyone suggest a faster in built function to achieve this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Write a function that will return a random int between 1-6
def roll_die():
    x = np.random.random_integers(6)
    return x
#A function to calculate the sum of 2 dice using a while loop
def rolling2(x):
    n=0
    while(n < rolls):
        sum = roll_die() + roll_die()
        arr[n] = sum
        sum = 0
        n = n + 1

#A function to calculate the sum of 3 dice using a while loop
def rolling3(x):
    n=0
    while(n < rolls):
        sum = roll_die() + roll_die() + roll_die()
        arr[n] = sum
        sum = 0
        n = n + 1

rolls = int (input("How many times will you roll 2 dice?"))
#Initialise 2 arrays to store values
arr = np.zeros(rolls)
arr1 = np.zeros(rolls)
#Calling rolling functions
rolling2(arr)
print (arr)

rolling3(arr1)
print(arr1)
#Plot graph using matplotlib methods and functions
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[0].hist(arr, bins=11)
ax[0].set_xlabel("Sum of 2 Dice")
ax[0].set_label("Frequency")
ax[0].set_title("Frequency of the Sum of Rolling 2 dice")

ax[1].hist(arr, bins=16)
ax[1].set_xlabel("Sum of 3 Dice")
ax[1].set_label("Frequency")
ax[1].set_title("Frequency of the Sum of Rolling 3 dice")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I would suggest going to code review - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and sum directly two or three dice rolls in it:

I also removed your use of initalized arrays as it is not needed. It's better to use the `return` value than modifying arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# A function that will return a random int between 1-6.
def roll_die():
    return np.random.random_integers(6)

# A function to calculate the sum of 2 dice rolls.
def rolling2(rolls):
    return [(roll_die() + roll_die()) for n in range(rolls)]

# A function to calculate the sum of 3 dice rolls.
def rolling3(rolls):
    return [(roll_die() + roll_die() + roll_die()) for n in range(rolls)]

rolls = int(input("How many times will you roll 2 dice?"))
array2 = rolling2(rolls)
array3 = rolling3(rolls)
print(array2)
print(array3)

# Plot graph using matplotlib methods and functions.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[0].hist(array2, bins=11)
ax[0].set_xlabel("Sum of 2 dices")
ax[0].set_label("Frequency")
ax[0].set_title("Frequency of the Sum of Rolling 2 dice")

ax[1].hist(array3, bins=16)
ax[1].set_xlabel("Sum of 3 dices")
ax[1].set_label("Frequency")
ax[1].set_title("Frequency of the Sum of Rolling 3 dice")
plt.show()
```

It would also be nice to write a function to roll any amount of dices any number of times. Here is it:

```
def roll_dices(dices, rolls):
    return [sum(roll_die() for _ in range(dices)) for _ in range(rolls)]
```

Then you can call `roll_dices(2, rolls)` instead of `rolling2(rolls)`.

Comment: Got to bloody love list comprehension! That's made it infinitely easier. And the nested for loops make a lot of sense as well. 1 to select the die, and the other to roll it n times.

Comment: @KishanBhatt Indeed! It's a very handy way to produce lists quickly. Here you do not have too many elements, but list comprehensions are always faster than for loops and appends. They are just less readable if the elements of the list are too complex.